# What's the best way to return List of data from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `List<MyModel>` that I am returning from controller to `view`

Shall I create a new class to hold this `List` and return object of the new class or I can return the `List` itself..

which one is a better programming practice ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your exact requirements are, consider the below two scenarios.

1. ***Using MVC webapi with any js framework like angular/jquery or returning partial view.***
   You just want to bind the list to a grid and that grid will be updated with new data from same controller action. In this scenario its better to return the list instead of view model, this will ensure that only required data is sent back to view.

``

```
[HttpPost]
public List<string> Index(string txtJsonIn)
{
 return new List<string>(); 
}
```

2. ***Using MVC without any js/ajax calls***
   In this case the view will be loaded with values from ViewModel everytime, so if you just keep the List as your return value from action, it will be hard to add new property in future.

   ```
   class MyViewModel
   {
       List<string> MyList { get; set; } //Your list that you need right now
       string PropertyThatCanBeAddedInFuture { get; set; }
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public MyViewModel Index(string txtJsonIn)
   {

       return new MyViewModel(); 
   }
   ```

You can write the view as below

```
    @foreach (string str in Model.MyList)
    {
      <tr>@str</tr>
    }
```

- Also using viewModels is always a good way to have loose coupled code, don't directly use any model from database, instead use Automapper to map your viewmodel to models from database.

Answer (score 2):

In a partial view I have often used an IEnumerable where there is repeating logic

```
@model IEnumerable<Result>

@foreach (Result res in Model)
{
    <div data-id="@res.ID">
        <p>
        <!-- Code goes here -->
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`View-model` is just a conceptual term in MVC's presentation layer. Technically it's just a concrete class.

So real question here whether to use `View-model`/`class` or directly pass `List`.

Now back to the point - Wrapping 'only' list in another class will yield nothing unless you have few other members to be wrapped and passed to view. If there's something more than a `List` that your view needs, create a class (call it View-model in MVC) to wrap all that stuff and pass it to view.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no reason to create a view model other than personal preference if you just have that one property UNLESS there is any chance that you will be adding more properties in the future.

However it is best practice to utilize interfaces whenever possible to keep your code decoupled. That said you should switch it to IEnumerable instead of list.

Answer (score 1):

I always create a viewmodel, to pass data to my view, populate it in your controller and then pass it to your view. This is a clean way of working in MVC.

TIP : Make a new folder ViewModels in your Models folder.
The same way with Entities, never directly use your entities , use viewmodels that provide just the things you need in your views. Also take a look at Data Annotations , these can come in handy when using a viewmodel for form validation etc...

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a viewmodel like Jelman said and in it just declare a list of your model like this by creating another class file in your model folder that is going to contain your list of model

```
namespace projectname.Models
{

  public class ModelNameViewModel
  { 
   public List<ListOfModel> { get; set; }
  }

}
```

or you could simply Change the declaration on the top of your view to have a list of your model like this if there is no other field you need to add to the model

```
@model List<YourModelName>
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this wrapping if there's only List in it?

Comment: I said this since he asked for the best practice, normally for only a list I would just change to a List on top of my View but I thought that helping him get to know ViewModel could serve him

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1):

While you can return that model to the view, chances are that not all data will be used in the view. Therefore we create view model classes which only hold data relevant to the view and we use a mapper (take a look at AutoMapper) to map between the two objects.

While this adds another class to manage, it keeps the domain model nice and clean and without any "view specific" properties (such as lists used in drop-downs etc.)

What you end up returning will end up being whatever you need in the view, as you might want to have some other data (or metadata) with that collection, in which case an object wrapper will be used.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is more correct to create a new model containing a list. If tomorrow you need to add a new property, you can easily add it to this model without changing viewmodel in your view.

Compare:

You have a model with a list of objects:

```
class MyModel
{
    public List<int> Comments {get;set;}
}
```

Your view looks like this:

```
@model MyModel
foreach(var comment in Model.Comments)
...
```

and when you need to add new property, you an easily do this:

```
class MyModel
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public List<int> Comments {get;set;}
}
```

your view will looks like

```
@model MyModel
...
Model.Title
...
foreach(var comment in Model.Comments)
...
```

So you do not need to change the model type in the controller and in the view, you simply add new properties to the created model